# how to fix movement of this sprite class (Enemy)

Tags: python

I am making a game and my Enemy which is a sprite class is not moving.

I tried searching for some solutions but haven't found any.

```
import turtle
import os
import random

#create sprite
class Sprite(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self, shape = spriteshape)
        self.speed(0)
        self.penup()
        self.color(color)
        self.fd(0)
        self.goto(startx, starty)
        self.speed = 1
    def move(self):
        self.fd(self.speed)



# Set up the screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("player v enemy")
# Draw border
border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300, -300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(5)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()
# Create the player turtle
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("yellow")
player.shape("square")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -250)
player.shapesize(2.3, 2.3)

playerspeed = 20
# create enemy
class Enemy(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        Sprite.__init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty)
        self.speed = 6


# player movement
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    if x < -280:
        x = - 280
    player.setx(x)


def move_right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    if x > 280:
        x = 280
    player.setx(x)


# keybinds
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")
#create sprite
enemy= Enemy("circle" ,"red", -200,250)
#main game loop
while True:
    Enemy.move()
```

I expect the enemy to move but it won't budge

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\prana\Desktop\game.py\players v enemys.py", line 78, in
>   
>       Enemy.move() TypeError: move() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using Enemy instead u should use enemy which is the object of Enemy class which extends the Sprite super class so change Enemy.move() to enemy.move()

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are not familiar with Python's class, hope code example below would help you.

```py
In [2]: class T:
   ...:     def a(self):
   ...:         print(self)
   ...:

In [3]: T.a
Out[3]: <function __main__.T.a(self)>

In [4]: T.a('anything is ok for T, but have to exsit')
anything is ok for T, but have to exsit

In [5]: T.a()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7c020799baa4> in <module>
----> 1 T.a()

TypeError: a() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

In [6]: t = T()

In [7]: t.a
Out[7]: <bound method T.a of <__main__.T object at 0x10e3c9dd8>>

In [8]: t.a()
<__main__.T object at 0x10e3c9dd8>

In [9]: T.a(t)
<__main__.T object at 0x10e3c9dd8>
```